# How to remove already installed MySQL and re-install from source

Tags: mysql, installation

It was installed by rpm.
But need to install from source to add new features to it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get yourself into the unmaintainable mess that is a package-based server with loads of stuff installed from sources on it.  The best approach for preserving your sanity is to get the SRPM for MySQL and build a newer version with your own modifications, then store your resulting SRPM and RPMs so that you can redeploy them elsewhere easily.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Jon just means that when you compile from source, do it in a way that will be supported by your distribution, rather than downloading the tarball from the MySQL site and compiling like that. Look for the SRPM (source RPM) and use that. More information here - http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Answer (score 1):

You can just uninstall the rpm package, but it's not a good option because unless you plan to regularly rebuild, you'll miss out on potentially important updates. Depending on what features you need, you should consider finding a RPM repository that is already maintained.

MySQL has it's own repositories:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/

as has MariaDB:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/yum/#using-the-mariadb-repository-configuration-tool

and also there is Percona:
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html#installing-percona-server-from-percona-yum-repository

I haven't tested these, but it's possible that at least with the MySQL repo, it will be a drop-in replacement, meaning you can just run yum upgrade and will have the new MySQL version installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql | xargs echo rpm -e
```

I used rpm and not yum/urpmi/apt-get/smart since you did not say which RPM based distro are you using.

Now to the real question: what  feature of mysql you need and is missing? Something smells funny in your question.

PS: Please remove the echo after the `xargs` in the command after you are sure this is what you want to do.

Comment: I need to add sphinx engine to it.

Answer (score 0):

I routinely install things from source and never use SRPMs, but I always make very sure never to install in the same places where the RPMs install things.  (/usr/local was intended for that; a ./configure script is usually preconfigured to install things there, but if software comes with something else, e.g. just a Makefile, be wary and check.  Best to create a special user `local` who owns /usr/local, and do all your installation from source as local instead of as `root`, that way you'll get permission errors if the installation process tries to write to places you want it to stay away from).

Answer (score 0):

rpm -qa | grep -i mysql

yum remove mysql*

then you can install tar etc.